# Proper way to unit test beforeFilter() and beforeRender() in AppController

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm writing unit tests for a new site I'm working on that uses CakePHP 2.3. Everything's going smoothly, except for one thing. I want to test the beforeFilter() and beforeRender() functions. beforeFilter() I can test easily enough by creating a mock object

```
$app_controller_mock = $this->generate(
    'App',
    array(
        'components' => array(
            'Session'
        )
    )
);
$app_controller_mock->beforeFilter();
```

That will run the function, but it won't give me the useful stuff like `$this->vars`, `$this->content`, etc. On this particular function that's ok, but in my beforeRender() I'm manually setting a viewVar that I want to check for in my test case.

```
$app_controller_mock->beforeRender();
$this->assertNotNull($this->vars['controller_name'], "'controller_name' viewVar is null");
```

When I do the above, I get the following error:

```
'controller_name' viewVar is null
Failed asserting that null is not null.
```

What's the "proper" way to do this?

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't the viewVars be located in `$app_controller->viewVars['xxx']`?

Comment: They are. I wanted to use the built in testAction() though. I suppose calling it manually and just checking viewVars will work for the time being. If my app gets much more complex though it could get hairy.

Comment: @Derek I posted an answer having just now noticed how old the question is, but I hope it helps someone in the future (as I'm sure you've figured out a solution that works for you by now)

Answer (score 0):

Something I usually do is dispatch a full request, which ensures all integrated components exist for `beforeFilter` and `beforeRender`.

Sometimes, a dummy controller is helpful:

```
App::uses('ControllerTestCase', 'TestSuite');
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class MockFiltersController extends AppController {
    public $controllerVar = 'something';

    public function action($var1 = null) {
        // can be helpful to set other vars, or
        // set something on the controller
        $this->controllerVar = $var1;
        $this->set(compact($var1));
    }
}

class AppControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {

    public function testBeforeRender() {
        $this->testAction('/mock_filters/action/test', array(
            'method' => 'GET'
        ));
        // ensure view vars are set
        $this->assertEquals('test', $this->vars['var1']);
        // other assertions for beforeRender items
    }

}
```

Then repeat for `beforeFilter`, mocking using `generate()` as necessary.

The `$this->vars`, `content`, `view`, etc. variables are only set when using `ControllerTestCase::testAction` to run an integration test.

Using this methods seems to be effective for me, as I can check for variables that are changed on the controller itself, integration with various components, and of course view variables being set.